# How to Copy Selected Entities From One Drawing to Another in Autocad Using C#

Tags: c#, autocad

I need to Export some entities from the source drawing file to another drawing  file in autocad. I am interacting with autocad in interface(COM) type. Can anybody give some suggestion to do this.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

AcadDatabase.CopyObjects should work for you. There is a documentation and sample at http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-D9E0A89C-2D81-4141-8B88-B9AC6EAABD62